# AWS Signature V2: generate a signature for a Query request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, amazon-web-services, hash

i am trying to re-create AWS signature version 2 authentication on javascript, what i have right now is

```
String.prototype.getBytes = () => {
    return this.toString()
        .split('')
        .map((i) => i.charCodeAt(0));
};

let key = 'redacted_access_key_id';

const bytes = key.getBytes();

let signingKey = crypto.HmacSHA256(bytes, key);

let data = JSON.stringify({ lang: 'en', pageNumber: 0, pageSize: 20 });

const contentMd5 = crypto.MD5(data).toString();

data = data.getBytes();

signingKey = crypto.HmacSHA256(data, key);

const result = Buffer.from(signingKey.toString()).toString('base64');
```

Which outputs something like

```
ZGY0MmI3MDVjNmJlNzY5ZWYwZjU1ZTc5MDhhOGNkYzI3ZWVjYzQ5ODBmY2M1NGI5NTc2MmVmNTY1NzEwNjhhMA==
```

which is incorrect, because the hash should be exactly 28 characters in length. Now the AWS signature version 2 auth docs show how it is being made, but only in java

```
import java.security.SignatureException;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import com.amazonaws.util.*;

/**
* This class defines common routines for generating
* authentication signatures for AWS Platform requests.
*/
public class Signature {
    private static final String HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA256";
    public static String calculateRFC2104HMAC(String data, String key)
    throws java.security.SignatureException
    {
        String result;
        try {

            // Get an hmac_sha256 key from the raw key bytes.
            SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);

            // Get an hmac_sha256 Mac instance and initialize with the signing key.
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
            mac.init(signingKey);

            // Compute the hmac on input data bytes.
            byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            // Base64-encode the hmac by using the utility in the SDK
            result = BinaryUtils.toBase64(rawHmac);
            

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SignatureException("Failed to generate HMAC : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I am trying to recreate this exact same code in javascript but something is wrong. Can someone please help me with this, i cant find any examples in javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: You could just use the [aws-sign-v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sign-v2) package (or its [source code](https://github.com/aellison5505/aws2/blob/master/aws2.js) inline).

Comment: agree with @jarmod, don't reinvent the wheel and use other packages that already have the signing logic... i have gone done the path of trying to write the signing logic myself and you'll keep encountering bugs in your code with edge cases... just use a library that is already well tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is the equivalent of the Java version of `calculateRFC2104HMAC` in JS.

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

const calculateRFC2104HMAC = (data, key) => {
    const rawHmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(data), CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key));
    return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(rawHmac);
}
```

Sample usage based on the example on [AWS Signature V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html) page

```
const urlSafeSignature = (data, key) => encodeURIComponent(calculateRFC2104HMAC(data, key));

const data = 
`GET
elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com
/
AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&Action=DescribeJobFlows&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2011-10-03T15%3A19%3A30&Version=2009-03-31`
const key = `wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY`
console.log(urlSafeSignature(data, key));
```

The documentation advises to use [AWS Signature V4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) which has a AWS published library on NPM [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/signature-v4). The AWS signed requests are for AWS Services and the signature in the request helps validating the request, prevents replay attacks. I'm not sure what you are trying to send in the following code and for which AWS service.

```
let data = JSON.stringify({ lang: 'en', pageNumber: 0, pageSize: 20 });
```

You must provide all details required to sign a request as per the AWS documentation.